# Access 2007: Editing all records in a linked table On Click via the front end

Tags: ms-access, vba

I had a button on a form that would run a data macro that would mark all records prior to today's date.  In other words:

```
For Each Record in TblEvents
 Where Condition = [TblEvents].[EndDate]<Date()
 Edit Record
   Set Field [TblEvents].[passed]=True
```

When I split the database, the button on the form stopped working (d'oh).

I still need this functionality somehow. Is this possible?  I've only just started learning VBA, but I know setField and editRecord options are non-existent outside of data macros in the builder.

Comment: How are you executing your SQL String? Is it using CurrentDb.Execute? Can you post the lines where you are executing the SQL?

Comment: I used the Named Macro builder/wizard thing that came built in with Access so it was basically just running straight off the table.  The problem is, after I split the database, I can't run data macros on the front end. I get a "Data Macro" cannot be found message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your macro operation could translate to an Access SQL `UPDATE` easily, assuming *TblEvents* is now a link to the table in your backend database.  And you can execute that statement from a `DAO.Database` object reference.

Include code similar to this in your command button's click event:

```vb
Dim strUpdate As String
Dim db As DAO.Database

strUpdate = "UPDATE TblEvents" & vbCrLf & _
    "SET [Passed] = True" & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE [EndDate] < Date();"
Debug.Print strUpdate  '<- examine completed statement text in Immediate window
                       ' Ctrl+g will take you there
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute strUpdate, dbFailOnError
MsgBox db.RecordsAffected & " row(s) updated."
```